# Proof by Cases [discrete mathematics]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I've come across this interesting proof question that I'm trying to solve but I'm rather confused about how to go about starting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

> Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $n^3+4n+2$ is not
>   divisible by 4.  Hint: divide the proof into two cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint : First assume that $n$ is odd, then that $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume

1) $n$ is odd:

$n=2k+1, k=0,1,2,....$

$(2k+1)^3+4(2k+1)+2=$

$1+3(2k)+3(2k)^2 +(2k)^3+$

$8k+6=$

$[3(2k)^2+ (2k)^3]+7(2k+1)$;

The first term (in brackets) is divisible by $4$,

$7(2k+1)$ is not (why?).

Hence $f(n)$ is not divisible by $4$ for odd $n$.

2) Let $n$ be even,  $n=2k$, k=1,2,... and complete the proof.

Comment: egreg.Why delete your answer? Straightforward, nice.While mine is contorted.:)

Answer (score 1):

$$n^3+4n+2\equiv n^3+2\mod4$$When $n$ is odd, $n^3$ is odd and so is $n^3+2$. When $n$ is even, $2|n\implies 4|n^3\implies n^3+2\equiv2\mod4$.